# Cypress - find nested properties in json file

Tags: json, cypress, fixtures

I am struggling with the following situation. I create a new user via a web page, which I save to a json file. But my tests in cypress can not search 'deep' in the file.

This is how my json file looks like:

```
{
  "customers" : [ {
    "customerId" : "123456",
    ...
   } ],
  "error" : ""
}
```

And this is how I load this json file in my test:

```
beforeEach('Load fixture', function () {

    cy.fixture('registerNewCustomers').its('customers').as('testdata');
    }); 
    ...
    cy.get('@testdata').then((testdata) => {

            cy.get('#inputLoginID').type(testdata.customerId);
```

My test can not read the nested 'customerId', but if I move it one level up to "customers" level, my test is finding it and its value.

```
{
  "customers" : [ {
    ...
    ...
   } ],
  "error" : "",
  "customerId" : "123456",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`customers` (which is saved as the alias `testdata`) is an array, so you would need to index the array.

If you know which customer you want, e.g to pick the 4th customer

```
cy.get('#inputLoginID').type(testdata[3].customerId)
```

If you've just added the customer, and therefore want the last one,

```
cy.get('#inputLoginID').type(testdata[testdata.length -1].customerId)
```